Google sheets Dynamic list that changes with criteria for planning usage of loading docks
I need to be able to create a dynamic list of allocted loading docks that changes daily based on a set of criteria.
for context:
Warehouse has 26 loading docks,
There are 4 trailer types and a dispach plan that changes daily.
trailer types  Small(preference to small docks but can use regular) , regular , large  and Special
there are 4 types of Docks - Small * 4, regular *14, large *6 and Special *2
The docks are used potentially 5 times for each 24 hours.
The dispach plan has the following structure:(this continues for up to
(Dispatch time) 06:00 - (load ref) xxx - (type) Small
(Dispatch time) 06:00 - (load ref) xx1 - (type) Small
(Dispatch time) 06:05 - (load ref) xx2 - (type) regular
(Dispatch time) 06:07 - (load ref) xx3 - (type) Large
Another constraint is that each dock needs to have at least 90 mins between each usage(dispatch time)
Also need to be able to take any dock out of use for mainanance.
my knowledge of google sheets is ok, but nowhere near expert.
I have managed to create a repeating list based on counting the number of docks available, that part is easy.
I am struggling to find a way to allocate based on type and time restrints.
here is a link with some data that I can share:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Nyb3F4Elc9iap2PlLX3C-ZhoTebsj9xDaqTMw-L7zU/edit
